# Different way of parsing through value part of key-value pair in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a key-value pair that looks something like this ($ctrl.displayData)-

```
143:"/this/is/a/very/long/fil22↵/this/is/a/very/long/file/path.php↵anotherone.php↵newfilel123.php"
```

It saves file names and when I display it with an ng-repeat, file names are displayed in newlines (just as I want).

For display I use-

```
<div>
    <div id="outputDiv" ng-click="$ctrl.deleteRow(displayData)" ng-repeat="displayData in $ctrl.displayData">{{displayData}}</div>
</div>
```

The function deleteRow() is pretty basic as of now-

```
ctrl.deleteRow = function(index){
    console.log(index);
}
```

But when I loop through using ng-repeat, the entire **{{displayData}}** gets printed in just one iteration, so if I were to call a function like **deleteRow()** on click of any one file name, it just returns the entire set of file names each time (and not the particular file name that I have clicked on).

Is there a way of looping through **$ctrl.displayData** in such a way that on clicking any particular file name, the function is called only for that file name.

Comment: You should iterate an array or object in ng-repeat, currently you pass an object with a single property

Comment: Is your `$ctrl.displayData` an array? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: Even if it is an array, it gets saved as-

{"143":"/this/is/a/very/long/fil22\n/this/is/a/very/long/file/path.php\nanotherone.php\nnewfilel123.php"}

Still gets printed in a single iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could you use javascript split?

```js
// <body ng-app='myApp' binds to the app being created below.
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

// Register MyController object to this app
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', MyController]);    

// We define a simple controller constructor.
function MyController($scope) {
   $scope.files = "/this/is/a/very/long/fil22 \n /this/is/a/very/long/file/path.php \n anotherone.php \n newfilel123.php"

  $scope.split = function(s) {
    return s.split('\n');
  }

  $scope.doStuff = function(d) {
    console.log(d);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller='MyController'>
    <p ng-repeat="d in split(files)">
      <span ng-click="doStuff(d)">{{d}}</span>
    </p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: $scope.files is in the form of this originally-
143:"/this/is/a/very/long/fil22↵/this/is/a/very/long/file/path.php↵anotherone.php↵newfilel123.php"                 
I get an error with the ng-repeat-
ng-repeat="displayData in $ctrl.split($ctrl.displayData)"

Comment: Hey I was able to solve it. I'll be sharing the solution in sometime. Thanks for your effort, it gave me the correct direction.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
I handled it inside the JS controller(using split there)
ctrl.arrayList = new Array();
for(var i in ctrl.displayData) {
    ctrl.arrayList = ctrl.displayData[i].split('\n');
}
After this I use an ng-repeat on the array ctrl.arrayList for display.

Answer (score 0):

I handled it inside the JS controller (using split there).

```
ctrl.arrayList = new Array(); 
for(var i in ctrl.displayData) { 
    ctrl.arrayList = ctrl.displayData[i].split('\n'); 
}
return ctrl.arrayList;
```

After this I use an ng-repeat on the array ctrl.arrayList for display inside the HTML file.